# MYSQL Comparing previous year by same week day for each timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, pivot

I have a number of sales from different outlets. I want to create a MySql query that will group sales transactions by date and by store but also have a column showing the previous year's sales on the nearest day of the week.

This is my dataset:

```
|id     |folderCounter_id|incasso |scontrini|timestamp          |
|-------|----------------|--------|---------|-------------------|
|189.712|131             |783,61  |4        |2024-01-08 06:00:00|
|189.713|131             |531,41  |36       |2024-01-08 08:00:00|
|189.714|131             |2.650,45|74       |2024-01-08 09:00:00|
|189.715|131             |4.140,04|141      |2024-01-08 10:00:00|
|189.716|131             |5.236,63|142      |2024-01-08 11:00:00|
|189.717|131             |7.043,62|202      |2024-01-08 12:00:00|
|189.718|131             |3.796,72|118      |2024-01-08 13:00:00|
|189.719|131             |4.375,61|118      |2024-01-08 14:00:00|
|189.720|131             |4.125,11|137      |2024-01-08 15:00:00|
|189.721|131             |4.346,73|134      |2024-01-08 16:00:00|
|189.722|131             |4.848,3 |144      |2024-01-08 17:00:00|
|189.723|131             |6.408,3 |209      |2024-01-08 18:00:00|
|189.724|131             |6.270,29|176      |2024-01-08 19:00:00|
|189.725|131             |3.482,77|113      |2024-01-08 20:00:00|
|189.726|131             |115,24  |2        |2024-01-08 21:00:00|
|189.727|53              |0       |0        |2024-01-08 07:00:00|
|189.728|53              |671,49  |50       |2024-01-08 08:00:00|
|189.729|53              |1.519,28|73       |2024-01-08 09:00:00|
|189.730|53              |2.918,88|122      |2024-01-08 10:00:00|
|189.731|53              |5.628,6 |184      |2024-01-08 11:00:00|
|189.732|53              |4.880,91|165      |2024-01-08 12:00:00|
|189.733|53              |3.288,26|116      |2024-01-08 13:00:00|
|189.734|53              |1.908,28|85       |2024-01-08 14:00:00|
|189.735|53              |3.786,79|113      |2024-01-08 15:00:00|
.
.
.
|189.736|131             |3.672,45|115      |2023-01-09 07:00:00|
|189.737|131             |5.241,46|164      |2023-01-09 09:00:00|
|189.738|131             |5.776,72|162      |2023-01-09 10:00:00|
|189.739|131             |5.830,12|190      |2023-01-09 12:00:00|
|189.740|131             |2.726,45|85       |2023-01-09 13:00:00|
|189.741|131             |0       |0        |2023-01-09 14:00:00|
|189.742|131             |0       |0        |2023-01-09 15:00:00|
|189.743|131             |1.152,64|42       |2023-01-09 16:00:00|
```

I created this query:

```
select t1.date as 'timestamp', t1.folderCounter_id as 'folderCounter_id', t1.incasso as 
'incasso', t2.incasso as 'last_yr_incasso', t1.scontrini as 'scontrini', t2.scontrini 
as 'last_yr_scontrini'
from(
SELECT cr.`timestamp` as date, cr.folderCounter_id, cr.incasso as incasso, cr.scontrini 
as scontrini
from CashRegister cr
group by cr.`timestamp`, cr.folderCounter_id 
) t1
left join(
SELECT cr.`timestamp` as date, cr.incasso as incasso, cr.scontrini as scontrini
from CashRegister cr
group by cr.`timestamp`, cr.folderCounter_id 
) t2
on DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 52 WEEK) = t2.date
and t1.folderCounter_id = t2.folderCounter_id
order by t1.date asc
```

And this is the output:

```
|timestamp          |folderCounter_id|incasso |last_yr_incasso|scontrini|last_yr_contrini|
|-------------------|----------------|----------|---------------|---------|----------------|
|2024-01-08 10:00:00|131             |4.140,04   |5.241,46       |141     |162             |
```

However, it does not return the values of the first table t2 which are not present on t1.

```
|timestamp          |folderCounter_id|incasso |last_yr_incasso|scontrini|last_yr_contrini|
|-------------------|----------------|--------|---------------|---------|----------------|
|2024-01-08 07:00:00|131             |NULL    |3.672,45       |NULL     |115             |
```

How can I modify the query so that it also returns values that are not present?
All timestamps, including those from the previous year, must be included in the first column.

I tried doing a full outer join but I can't create a single column with the timestamps (in this case I have to make 2 otherwise the first has a NULL value)

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Define "nearest day of week". The definition is always ambiguous.

Comment: @SalmanA i would compare the same week day with previous year week day. for example monday 8 January 2024 (week 2of 2024) compare monday 9 January 2023 (week 2 of 2023)

Comment: Actually, subtracting 52 weeks is acceptable. Otherwise my next question would be how do you define first week of the year.

Comment: @SalmanA for my case: monday 8 January 2024 08:00:00 (week 2of 2024) compare monday 9 January 2023 08:00:00 (week 2 of 2023)

Comment: @SalmanA The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the first Thursday of the Gregorian year (i.e. of January) i

Answer (score 0):

You must gather all dates then leftjoin both tables to it.

Schematically:

```
SELECT *
-- collect all existing datetimes, with according correction
FROM (SELECT timestamp FROM table WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2024
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT timestamp + INTERVAL 52 WEEK FROM table WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2023) AS dates
-- join existing data for 2024
LEFT JOIN table t1 ON dates.timestamp = t1.timestamp AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2024
-- join existing data for 2023
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON dates.timestamp - INTERVAL 52 WEEK = t2.timestamp AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2023
```

Comment: Thanks, but the last year income sales must be for each timestamp not for only year 2024 and 2023. For example 2023 compare with 2022 and so on

Comment: The dataset start from year 2015

Comment: @peppe71-19 I provide not a solution but a pattern which demonstrates one of the techniques which allows to emulate FULL JOIN in MySQL.